# Simple Jquery event not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an external `.js` file and I'm not sure if it's the `.js` fault.

Here is the `.js` file: (`/js/scripts.js`)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#about_link').click( function() {
        $('.middleface img').css('display','none');
        $('.aboutface').css('display','');
    });
});
```

I have three links (`index`, `about`, `contact`) each with `#index_link`, `#about_link` & `#contact_link` respectively.

What I'm trying to do is by clicking the About `<a>` link, the image inside `.middleface` `div` should disappear, and the `.aboutface` `div` should appear.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- navigation -->
<div class="navbar">
     <div class="navlinks">
        <a type="button" id="index_link">Index</a>
        <a type="button" id="about_link">About</a>
        <a type="button" id="contact_link">Contact</a>
             </div> 
</div>
<!-- middlecontent -->
<div class="middleface">
    <img id="middle_image" src="images/blabla2.png" alt="blabla">
    <!-- aboutpage -->
            <div class="aboutface"></div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

...and the css

```css
.middleface {
    background-image:url('images/blabla1.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
}

#middle_image {
    height: 230px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
}

.middleface img{}

.aboutface {
    display:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:grey;
    width:800px;
    height:280px;
}
```

Comment: Try to add jQuery with full path: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js`.

Comment: and make sure your `js` folder is beside your `html` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#about_link').click( function() {
        $('.middleface img').css('display','none');
        $('.aboutface').css('display','block');
        });
    });
```

you can also use hide and show:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    $('#about_link').click( function() {
        $('.middleface img').hide();
        $('.aboutface').show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i copy pasted it...but it still does'nt work :(. Perhaps a css/html problem?

Comment: Solved: Well what do you know, seems like the jquery link was not going through, after that everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few ideas to solve your problem :

1. Use the **`on()`** function instead of the `click()` (as recommended [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/))
2. Before attaching the click event unbind it, it avoids strange behaviors (double `click()`s ... )
3. Access HTML elements by id is faster than `.middleface img` => use `#middle_image`
4. To display the element use `display` `block` or `inline` but it is better to use jquery functions  `hide()` or `show()` or event `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` for an effect.

:

```
$('#about_link').unbind('click').on('click', function() {
     $('#middle_image').hide();
     $('.aboutface').show();
});
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#about_link').click( function() {
    $('#middleface').hide();
    $('.aboutface').show();
});
});
```

You can use the id of the image in the aboutface div in the show() line

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **preventDefault**() for the click event of the links like

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#about_link').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#middle_image').css('display','none');   //$('#middle_image').hide();
        $('.aboutface').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply display the div using block. Use this.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $(document).on('click','#about_link', function() {
     $('.middleface img#middle_image').css('display','none');
     $('.aboutface').css('display','block');
  });
});
```

Comment: Solved: Well what do you know, seems like the jquery link was not going through, after that everything works.